# Login using finger print default hardware android in my app same as (paytm money and Gpay, imobile, axis bank)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I checked 4 app paytm money, gpay, imobile, axis mobile. They used phone fingerprint to login there app can any one provide the logic behind that or tell me i am thinking is right or wrong

i think when they enable login with fingerprint from application setting they store id and password or some kind of token to authenticate from the (login api) for there server.  when app open and fingerprint is valid then a api call occurs using that id and password or token and then api call success and user log in there app.

plz correct me if i m wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The apps you mention are not a login using fingerprint. They used fingerprint to authenticate a valid user or owner of a mobile phone, thats it.

Touch Id /Face Id is a LocalAuthentication. It’s only check a TouchId/FaceId is enable or not. If enable validate a touchid/faceid and give you success as true and false if disable.

[follow the medium link you will understand how to implement local Authentication](https://link.medium.com/MeY19Mahg1)

You can not achieved a login with fingerprint concept because android or iPhone, they both store your identity into the device only. You can not sent to the sever through API calls.

There is another 3rd party library available for touch and face id authentication the named is

[SwiftPasscodeLock](https://github.com/zahlz/SwiftPasscodeLock)

Comment: i dont think app like imobile is only using fingerprint for local auth because user ned to enter 6 digit pin before opening app and after turning fingerprint on for app app did not ask for pin 

and pin is compulsory for banking app so there must me another process what they are using